# When forgot about the debtor

Tags: money, debt

Assalamualaikum! I recently come to know the seriousness of dying with debt. So borrowed a little money from some people. But now I cant remember from whom I took the money or whom I owe. Because its being years. They might also forgot otherwise they might ask me for that. Now what should I do because I am not able to recall anything regarding it.

Comment: This is the reason why Allah ordered to write debts down no matter how few they are in the longest verse of the qur'an. You may seek for this people by adressing the topic that you want to pay back your debts and forgot from whon you borrowed any one that feels addressed would tell you sooner or later. I'm expecting that you know the amount or the people for whom this could apply or it least those you could exclude.